# Hosting a Web Application on a local server

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

I have an application developed in asp.net. I'm trying to host it on a server so that my manager can access it from a different location. Since I'm not aware of how to process this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: May be [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) would provide a way forward to what you are looking for

Comment: You can read http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33487zw6.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If you're using web server IIS In the first step you need to :

1. Start menu write >> inetmgr
2. going to control panel and click administrative tools > IIS
3. Open IIS ->SItes --> Add web site and enetr the site name click OK
4. you may click on the Advance Settings.  from the right panel and modify some settings that you want to modify. In general it is not needed and you can keep it default.
5. Now, your website is ready to be browsed, you can right click on the website name (SampleWebSite in my case) and go to Manage Web Site > Browse and you should have an Internet Explorer window open displaying the default page of your website or web application. I suggest you to hosted with asphostportal.com because they are cheap and their support will help you.

Comment: My company need the application to be hosted on there own servers. Just wanted to know if it would require any version on windows server or IIS would do.

Comment: And also, do I need visual studio installed on the Windows server??

Comment: No, you dont need visual studio , because if you have developed Visual studio as your web config file, may have some tags that is not identified by the IIS. 
you can read in this article http://www.cheapaspnethostingreview.com/cheap-iis-hosting-tutorial-host-asp-net-application-on-the-web-server-iis/